# apt says "invalid signature"/"not signed" for all repos even if keys are there

Tags: 16.04, apt

When doing `apt update` I am getting error messages such as

```
Err:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                     
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
```

and

```
W: GPG error: http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
```

and

```
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

But the keys are all there and valid (confirmed using `apt-key list`). Also used `debsums` to confirm that all the main packages are OK.

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/3E5C1192 2010-09-20
uid                  Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case the problem lay in `busybox` being used for the main standard userland tools instead of the GNU ones, so the output of `readlink --help` is

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) multi-call binary.

Usage: readlink [-fnv] FILE

Display the value of a symlink

        -f      Canonicalize by following all symlinks
        -n      Don't add newline
        -v      Verbose
```

and `command -v readlink` points to `/usr/bin/readlink` which was a symlink to `/bin/busybox`. I confirmed that in a clean Ubuntu this is not the case.

Apparently someone accidentally ran `busybox --install`. The fix was to delete the symlinks pointing to `busybox` using `find /bin /sbin /usr -type l -lname /bin/busybox -delete`.